# Requesting class constant value in Ruby returns all defined values within this class

Tags: ruby

Hello I've encountered one interesting piece of code on Ruby project I've just joined. I tried to google explanation what is causing behaviour that I'm experiencing, but without any luck.

I've got class definition like this

```
class Values
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 3
end
```

At other place there is call for value like this Values::First
this returns

```
1
2
3
```

If I call Values::Second or Values::Third it correctly returns just single value.
Can someone explain why it happens when lines are ended with comma character?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, these are constants not class variables.

The commas mean that this is the same as

```
First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 3
```

Which is the same as

```
First = 1, (Second=2), (Third=3)
```

This sets Second and Third but is otherwise the same as

```
First = 1,2,3
```

Which sets First to the array [1,2,3]

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax defines `First` as an Array, while also defining `Second` as `2` and `Third` as `3` in the process.  Remove the commas to have `First` set to `1`:

```
class Values
    First = 1
    Second = 2
    Third = 3
end
```